# How to use Lightbox on AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, bootstrap-5

I am using Boostrap 5 and this Lightbox library https://trvswgnr.github.io/bs5-lightbox/

It **works fine on pages loaded normally** but it will not load on AJAX loaded content.

I have tried this code to make it work with AJAX but it did not work.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).Lightbox();
});
```

It returned this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Lightbox is not a function

Comment: `$(...).Lightbox is not a function` is pretty unambiguous. The Lightbox plugin is not loaded.  The documentation page you've linked to does not mention a jQuery plugin at all.

Comment: Where do you load Lightbox in your HTML?

Comment: @double-beep my HTML might look like this:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ajaxContent"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.7.7/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>  
</html>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the vanilla JS version, the script only adds event handlers to elements with the `data-toggle="lightbox"` attribute that are present *when the script loads*, hence new elements loaded via AJAX calls not working.

If you're able to use Node (or hack around not using node with a module loader like RequireJS), you can instantiate a new Lightbox when each new element loads, per the docs:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="foo"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const el = $(this);
    const lightbox = new Lightbox(el);
    lightbox.show();
});
```

Note that the correct syntax here is to create a new lightbox from the element and then use `lightbox.show()`... `$(this).Lightbox()` will never work.